# Why does this go code ignore the second inputed number?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main()  {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Enter String=>")
    a1, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    a1 = strings.Replace(a1, "\n", "", -1)
    b1 := strings.Split(a1, " ")
    var b2 [2]int
    for i := 0; i < 2 ; i++ {
        b2[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(b1[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(b2[0] + b2[1])
}
```

This code produces the following output

```
Enter String=> 5 6

5
```

But in Jetbrains Goland it produces the correct output.

Comment: It works for me assuming you expect that for inputs [5,6] the output should be 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows terminates lines with [CRLF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\r\n`). Use [strings.TrimSpace](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#TrimSpace), not [Replace](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replace).

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main()  {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Enter String=>")
    a1, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    a1 = strings.TrimSpace(a1)
    b1 := strings.Split(a1, " ")
    var b2 [2]int
    for i := 0; i < 2 ; i++ {
        b2[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(b1[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(b2[0] + b2[1])
}
```

Or, use [strings.Fields](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Fields) instead of Replace and [Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split).

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Enter String=>")
    a1, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    b1 := strings.Fields(a1)
    var b2 [2]int
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        b2[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(b1[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(b2[0] + b2[1])
}
```